# Change the font-awesome text font in select options

Tags: html, css, font-awesome

I want to change the text font for my options in a select box. The problem is that I also want to display icons before some options. If I change the font-style, the font-awesome icons won't be displayed and I don't think it is possible to style the options themselves, only the whole select box.

Here is some of my code:

```
  <div class="form-group">
    {{ Form::label('qualifications', 'Qualifications') }}<br>
    <select size="5" class="fa form-control" id="selectedqualification">
      <!-- displays an fa-warning icon after every qualification that's expiring -->
      @foreach ($employee_qualifications as $key => $qualification)
        @if($expiringQualifications->contains($qualification))
          <option value="{{$key}}">{{$qualification}} &#xf071;</option>
        @else
          <option value="{{$key}}">{{$qualification}}</option>
        @endif
      @endforeach
    </select>
    <button
       type="button"
       class="btn btn-default pull-right"
       data-toggle="modal"
       data-target="#qualificationModal"
       data-qualifications="{{ $qualifications }}"
       data-qualification_names="{{ $qualification_names }}">
       Add
    </button>
    <button type="button" id="removequali" class="btn btn-danger pull-right">Remove</button>
    <br>
    <br>
  </div>
```

Comment: You are probably going to have to use a custom dropdown plugin like [select2](https://select2.org/). It will allow you to [template your options](https://select2.org/dropdown#templating) so that you can add your icon. A basic select `option` will not allow the html markup needed to apply 2 different fonts in 1 option.

Comment: Hmm, okay, thank you. I'll try it out